# Dynamic columns for a table in ASP.NET MVC Razor using Angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I need to make a dynamic table in asp.net MVC razor for my assignment.
New column should be added on run time when user completely fill all the rows of 1st column. There is no limit of columns. On last entry row of each column, new column should be generated automatically.[image: Here is the sample image]

Time interval should be asked from user and new columns should be added according to the interval.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a minimal, complete, verifiable example in your question. In other words, show us what you've done! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you sir but to be honest I have done nothing. I am quit familiar with MVC but totally new to angularjs. I have been searching on web since couple of days but not succeeded yet.

Comment: Q1: So you want to only expand in -> that direction with added columns? Q2: What is the MVC part going to do? And since you know MVC do you have the code for this side already?
Q3: Why do you even need angularjs?

Comment: Q1: Yes, but actually i want to add new column, at start there should be only one column with limited rows and when user reach at the end row of first column, the next column should generate on runtime. Q2: This will be a page of MVC application, i have been given an assignment to do so. I have worked on MVC for other projects. Didn't have started this one. I think it will be on MVC view (I may be wrong, i just assume it) Q3: As i already said its an assignment to use angularjs on MVC view to get this work done. I have to do this task and i have very short time span. Thanks in advance

Comment: What if I leave angular. Can I do the same on MVC razor view. No matter how, just want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this you could build a dynamic table model in Angular using the following pattern:
**Column Model**
Define a model for your columns to describe the column and specify its titel and if the colum is dynamic:

```
$scope.columns = [
{
   title: 'Desc.',
   isDynamic: false,
   index: 0
},
{
   title: '30',
   isDynamic: true,
   index: 1
},
...
```

**Data Model**
Next define a model for the containing data which holds the values for each cell like this:

```
$scope.data = [
    {
       index: 0,
       values: ['Text', 0]
    },
    {
       index: 1,
       values: ['Text2', 0]
    },
];
```

**Logic for inserting columns**
Then you need some logic to determine if the edited row was filled completely and if so add a new one.
The edited row will be passed to the function as argument.

```
$scope.checkAddNewCol = function(rowData) {
    var addNewCol = true;
    $scope.columns.forEach(function(col){
            var colIndex = $scope.columns.indexOf(col);
            var value = value = rowData.values[colIndex];
            var isEmptyDynCol = col.isDynamic && (value === undefined || value === '');
            if (isEmptyDynCol){
                addNewCol = false;
            }
        });
    if (addNewCol){
        var newColIndex = $scope.columns.length;
        $scope.columns.push({
            title: 'New Cloumn [' + newColIndex + ']',
            isDynamic: true,
            index: newColIndex
        });
    }
};
```

**Put everything together**
At last put everything together in the HTML:
- Create the Header by enumerating through the columns
- Create all rows by enumerating through the data
- ng-changed on the inputs is used to trigger the logic which checks if new col is needed
Here you can see why the index properties are required, because you need them here in the HTML markup to construct the bindings (ng-model does not accept functions)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="col in columns"><strong>{{col.title}}</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-repeat="col in columns">
           <input ng-model="data[row.index].values[col.index]" ng-change="checkAddNewCol(row)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Summary**
You can find a complete example here: http://jsfiddle.net/edpqtop4/12/ 
there are some things missing like generating the correct title for new columns and storing the data but that is not directly related to the core of the question so I left it out here.